# Choice of asymptotic bound (O vs Θ) for three different implementations of algorithm to remove duplicates from list

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to get my head around asymptotic notation for time complexity. I understand that big-O is the upper bound and theta is a tight bound, but I'm confused as to when to use which, and why sometimes one is given rather than the other.

Specifically, for the three implementations of the same algorithm given below, the author has described the time complexity as O(n²), Ө(nlogn) and Ө(n) on average respectively.

I want to understand what goes on in the mind of an expert in these matters when making these assignments. Why is the fist given as Big-O, while the other two as theta, and why does the last mention average case while the other two don't?

Any help much appreciated.

```
def RemoveDuplicates(A):
    m = 0
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        if (not elem(A, m, A[i])):
            A[m] = A[i]
            m += 1
    return m


def elem(A, n, e):
    for i in range(0, n):
        if (A[i] == e):
            return 1
    return 0


A = [54, 26, 93, 54, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
RemoveDuplicates(A)
print(A)
# Time Complexity O(n²)


def RemoveDuplicates(A):
    A.sort()
    print(A)
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if (A[j] != A[i]):
            j += 1
            A[j] = A[i]

    print(A[:j + 1])


A = [54, 31, 93, 54, 77, 31, 44, 55, 93]
RemoveDuplicates(A)
# Time Complexity: Ө(nlogn) 

A = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 3, 4, 'b', 'c', 'd']
unique = []
helperSet = set()
for x in A:
    if x not in helperSet:
        unique.append(x)
        helperSet.add(x)

print(A)
print(unique)
# Time Complexity: Ө(n) on average
```

Comment: For the first case, the teacher wrote O(n²) and not Ө(n²) because there are cases where it might be faster than n²; for instance, if the array A is filled with copies of only one unique element, such as A = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ], then in this particular case the algorithm will take n operations instead of n². But it will never take more than n².

Comment: For the second case, the complexity of the algorithm will be the same as the complexity of `A.sort()`; the for-loop that follows is O(n), which is faster than `A.sort()`. So the complexity of the algorithm is that of sorting an array. The teacher assumed that this was always exactly n log(n). That's not entirely true - for instance, the implementation of `.sort()` in python is such that if you try to sort an array that is already sorted, it will be much faster.

Comment: For the third case, if we assume that `helperSet.add(x)` takes O(1) time complexity, then the algorithm is Ө(n), since it's just a for-loop. Now, if you look at the documentation of `set.add`, you'll read something like "set.add is almost-always O(1), unless you're extremely unlucky" (this has to do with hashing functions and probability of collision, because sets are usually implemented as hashmaps). So the teacher simplified this to "in average, set.add is O(1), so in average, our algorithm is Ө(n)".

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, the teacher wrote O(n²) and not Ө(n²) because there are cases where it might be faster than n²; for instance, if the array A is filled with copies of only one unique element, such as A = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ], then in this particular case the algorithm will take n operations instead of n². But it will never take more than n².

For the second case, the complexity of the algorithm will be the same as the complexity of `A.sort()`; the for-loop that follows is O(n), which is faster than `A.sort()`. So the complexity of the algorithm is that of sorting an array. The teacher assumed that this was always exactly n log(n). That's not entirely true - for instance, the implementation of `.sort()` in CPython is such that if you try to sort an array that is already sorted, it will be much faster.

For the third case, if we assume that `helperSet.add(x)` takes O(1) time complexity, then the algorithm is Ө(n), since it's just a for-loop. Now, if you look at the documentation of `set.add`, you'll read something like "set.add is almost-always O(1), unless you're extremely unlucky or you're under attack" (this has to do with hashing functions and probability of collision, because sets are usually implemented as hashmaps). So the teacher simplified this to "in average, set.add is O(1), so in average, our algorithm is Ө(n)".

Comment: "unless you're extremely unlucky" - Or "unless you're under attack" :-). The latter seems actually more likely to me.

Comment: In the first case, the teacher *should* have written Ө(n²), because it refers to the worst case input automatically, and there is indeed a tight lower-bound on the time taken for the worst case input.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically". Surely it depends on the exact English sentence used. If you say "the worst-case time complexity is Ө(n²)", then sure, it's about the worst-case. But if you say for instance "the time complexity of quicksort is Ө(n²)", people are going to disagree with you.

Comment: Indeed some people would disagree...  but they would be wrong :)  Unless stated otherwise, the complexity is for the worst case input.  We almost never care about the best case input.  The average case is important, but we specify that when that's what we're talking about.  Remember that O(n) is a *set of functions*.  The functions in the set are real functions.  Time complexity O(n) means that the *actual function* giving worst case time vs input size is in O(n).

Comment: @Stef Thanks for you answer. Many people seem keen to emphasise the difference between best/average/worst-case and Big-O, theta and omega notation. In your answer, what you say about the algorithm being possibly O(n^2) but sometimes O(n) suggests to me that the statement should be "in the worst case, this algorithm belongs to Θ(n^2)", since we know that we are discussing worst-case. It really baffles me the way people seem to jump about with these two ideas, claiming they are separate and then making statements which seems to show otherwise.

Comment: @Stef I'm not saying you are doing that, but I still haven't reached clarity on this issue. One thing that seems to make sense, if I've understood correctly, is that if it is known for certain that an algorithm ALWAYS performs within a certain class, then Θ is the way to go. Did I at least get that right?

Comment: @MattTimmermans "the teacher should have written Ө(n²), because it refers to the worst case input automatically," This is new to me. Are you saying Θ notation always implicitly refers to the worst case?

Comment: .. and if so, why do we have O?  Curiouser And curiouser... Hopefully the fog will clear for me at some point.

Comment: It seems possible to me, that when all is said and done, we can basically use big-O to pretty much mean "in the worst case", and avoid a lot of confusing detail that can be created when people use Θ and/or start discussing best/average/worst case. I mean, in general, for the purposes of knowing roughly how execution time will scale. Would that really be an egregious over-simplification, as some people seem to imply?

Comment: @RobinAndrews Don't confuse two things: theta- and big-oh-notations, which are a thing from mathematics to describe functions; and complexity analysis, which is from computer science to describe algorithms. In complexity analysis, we almost always talk about worst-case. When you have a mathematical function f(n) and say something like f(n) = O(n^2), or f(n) = Ө(n²), you're making a mathematical statement about function f. When you say "the algorithm's complexity is O(n^2)", without specifying what is n and what it is exactly you call the algorithm's complexity, it is up to the reader to guess.

Comment: And most of the times (but not always) `n` is the length of the input; and most of the times (but not always) we are talking about worst-case complexity, unless we explicitly specified otherwise.